# Trouble with ACCESS VBA INSERT INTO

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I am getting an error with this INSERT INTO that I just can not seem to figure out. The code iterates through a Dao recordset to append only certain records to a table.

```
    Dim maxDate As Variant

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlinsert As String

maxDate = DMax("[Eff Date]", "400_CF_BREAK_LOG")
Set db = CurrentDb


Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("860_APPEND_DIFFERENCES")
If Not rs.BOF Then
    'populate the table
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do
        If (rs![Eff Date] > maxDate Or IsNull(maxDate)) Then
            sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO 400_CF_BREAK_LOG (Eff Date, PrimarySecurity ID Number, CUSIP(Aladdin ID), IsrName, Asset Type, Metlife Port Code, Business Unit, Principal Difference, Total PAM Principal, Total Aladdin Principal,Income Difference, Total PAM Interest,Total Aladdin Interest,Total CF Difference,Total PAM CF,PAM Coupon)" & _
            " VALUES ('" & rs("Eff Date") & "', '" & rs("PrimarySecurity ID Number") & "', '" & rs("CUSIP(Aladdin ID)") & "', '" & rs("IsrName") & "', '" & rs("Asset Type") & "', '" & rs("Metlife Port Code") & "', '" & rs("Business Unit") & "', '" & rs("Principal Difference") & "',  '" & rs("Total PAM Principal") & "',  '" & rs("Total Aladdin Principal") & "','" & rs("Income Difference") & "', '" & rs("Total PAM Interest") & "', '" & rs("Total Aladdin Interest") & "', '" & rs("Total CF Difference") & "', '" & rs("Total PAM CF") & "', '" & rs("PAM Coupon") & "') "
            DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlinsert)
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End If
```

I keep getting Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement, but I have checked it over a couple times.

EDIT - Explanation. Tags

Comment: you cant use spaces, you need to use `[Eff Date]`

Comment: As @Nathan_Sav says, only there are a lot more names with spaces in your query than `[Eff Date]` alone, they all need to be enclosed in square brackets. Also, mind variable types. If [Eff Date] is a date and not a string, then you're handling it incorrectly. Also note that if the code you shared above is complete, it can be replaced by a single append query, and will run much more efficiently and be easier to debug.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Unfortunately, I can not run the append query as that adds a batch of records whereas I need to check each record then add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names with spaces or punctuation/special characters (only exception is underscore) need to be enclosed in [ ]. Best to avoid these in naming convention. However, references to the recordset fields with quote marks should work without enclosing in [ ]. An alternate syntax that would require [ ] is: `rs![Eff Date]`.

```
sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO 400_CF_BREAK_LOG ([Eff Date], [PrimarySecurity ID Number],  
[CUSIP(Aladdin ID)], IsrName, [Asset Type], [Metlife Port Code], [Business Unit],  
[Principal Difference], [Total PAM Principal], [Total Aladdin Principal],  
[Income Difference], [Total PAM Interest], [Total Aladdin Interest], [Total CF Difference],  
[Total PAM CF], [PAM Coupon])" & _  
" VALUES ('" & rs("Eff Date") & "', '" & rs("PrimarySecurity ID Number") & "', '" & 
rs("CUSIP(Aladdin ID)") & "', '" & rs("IsrName") & "', '" & rs("Asset Type") & "', '" & 
rs("Metlife Port Code") & "', '" & rs("Business Unit") & "', '" & rs("Principal Difference") & "',  '" & 
rs("Total PAM Principal") & "',  '" & rs("Total Aladdin Principal") & "','" & 
rs("Income Difference") & "', '" & rs("Total PAM Interest") & "', '" & 
rs("Total Aladdin Interest") & "', '" & rs("Total CF Difference") & "', '" & rs("Total PAM CF") & "', '" & 
rs("PAM Coupon") & "') "
```

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, I am using a legacy system not of my own design

Comment: Also, I just noticed use of apostrophe delimiters for what appear to be date/time and number fields. The apostrophe is supposed to be only for text fields. The # is for date/time and number type does not require delimiter. Are all fields of text type?

Comment: No, could you provide an example? Eff data is a date.

Comment: Actually, I just did a test of INSERT with the apostrophe delimiters for date/time and number fields and it does work. However, will not work in WHERE clause and since INSERT does not use WHERE clause, not an issue here. Just be aware for other SQL statements such as SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE.